# Why can't you follow a catch clause in Java with a semi-colon the same way you can for a loop?

Tags: java, syntax

In the same way that you can do a one line if statement, while loop, for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; someint += i++);

if(true);

while(waitForSomething());
```

Why can't you do the same with a try catch? Such as:

```
try{
    int a = 1, b = 0;
    int c = a/b;
} catch (Exception e);
```

Comment: Well i do believe that is because you need a block after the `catch(` so you need to have the `{   }`

Comment: for our own sake, `;` would make exception go completely unnoticed

Comment: Well it could be that you want to one-liner the e.printStackTrace(); so the block wouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: The other examples are inherited from earlier languages, the catch block can't be a semicolon - but you can omit a catch block (and use a `finally` block).

Comment: There's no consistency. Some constructs require code blocks, others don't. You'd have to ask the language designers why this particular decision was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `catch` clause *must* have a Block, while `for` and `if` statements just require a Statement.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; someint += i++);

if(true);
```

Actually means

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; someint += i++)
    ;

if(true)
    ;
```

See [JLS 14.9 The `if` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9):

> ```
> IfThenStatement:
>     if ( Expression ) Statement
> ```

Compare to [JLS 14.20 The `try` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20):

> ```
> TryStatement:
>     try Block Catches
> Catches:
>     CatchClause
>     Catches CatchClause
> CatchClause:
>     catch ( CatchFormalParameter ) Block
> ```

See how `if` statement ends with `Statement`,
while `try` statement ends with `Block`.

Comment: I understand that, but why couldn't you have something like
    catch(Exception e)
        e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @SamBurns Because that is not the syntax. See the Java Language Specification references I added.